# php include gives an error

Tags: php, include

i want to include my php file but i get an error

my page contains javascript

this is the error i am getting

```
[Thu Aug 05 15:38:01 2010] [error] [client 10.0.0.2] <br/><br/>Unexpexted output: \r\n<html>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src................
```

this is my server code , i am calling the page via ajax

```
function getPageContent(&$response){
  $PAGE_URL     = $_POST['PAGE_URL'];
  try{
     echo '../' . $PAGE_URL;
   }catch(Exception $ee){
    error_log($ee->getMessage());
 }
 $response->fields->frame_main = file_get_contents('../' . $PAGE_URL);
}
```

thank you

Comment: Post the relevant code please.

Comment: What is example value to `$PAGE_URL`?

Comment: its a name of the page 
for example , login.php

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to include a javascript file with PHP.. echo ' instead..

Comment: echo '../' . $PAGE_URL;    gives me     

<br/><br/>Unexpexted output: ../upload_application.php, referer: http://10.0.0.2/jtpc/index.php

Answer (score 0):

it looks like what you're trying to do is include a javascript file on demand. Without the full source (including what you're passing in the URL, it's a bit difficult to debug.

I feel like what you want to be saying here:

> $response->fields->frame_main = file_get_contents('../' . $PAGE_URL);

is actually

> $response->fields->frame_main = '../' . $PAGE_URL;

Since based on the output you've provided, it looks like you're accidentally reading the file into the  tag, rather than providing the filename.

One small point I feel obligated to bring up. Your code in it's current implementation seems like it would allow me to pass a POST variable like "../../../../../etc/passwd" and retreive the contents of that file. If you do end up reading in files on demand from the user, please validate them fully. Filtering them using a function like basename() may be of use.

Comment: how come they are the same ? , frame_main ,is the id of the div , my ajax will replace the div.innerHTML with that content

Comment: this is the way i got it working , 
function getPageContent(&$response){
  $PAGE_URL     = $_POST['PAGE_URL'];

  ob_start();
  require_once( '../' . $PAGE_URL );
  $contents = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  $response->fields->frame_main = $contents;
}

  but i had to separate the javascript file ,can i do that without separating the js ?